# How can I send 10x responses using Express API?

Tags: node.js, http, express, reverse-proxy

I'm in the process of implementing the send of early informational responses. This is a feature I'm trying with to optimize [h2o's push response feature described here (Ctrl+F for Server Push)](https://h2o.examp1e.net/configure/http2_directives.html) .

I was looking for a sane Express API to allow to flush an early 100 response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Link: </assets/layout.css>; rel=preload; as=style
...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
....
```

but was sadly unable to find it. I've also looked for the proper Node Response API, but the only thing I could find was copy-paste node's internal solution for `writeContinue`, which looks like this:

```
const common = require('_http_common')
const { CRLF } = common
let links = []

// fill up links

const earlyResponse = 'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue' + CRLF + links.map(link => `Link: ${link}`).join(CRLF) + CRLF + CRLF

res._writeRaw(earlyResponse, 'ascii', () => {
  res.status(200)send("blabla")
})
```

this kind of feels dirty, as `_writeRaw` appears to be private API, so I'd like to know what's the cleanest way to inject early responses there.

This is [in the process of being standardized under the 103 code](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kazuho-early-hints-status-code-00), so it's important to know how to accomplish this.

Comment: See my updated answer with for way to add custom headers to 100 Continue response.

Answer (score 3):

*(See updates below for a way to add custom headers to `100 Continue`)*

Express automatically sends the `100 Continue` if there is `Expect: 100-continue` header in the request.

See example:

```
const app = require('express')();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('xxx');
  res.json({ xxx: 1 });
});
app.listen(4433);
```

And send a request:

```
$ echo -ne 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nExpect: 100-continue\r\n\r\n' | nc localhost 4433
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9
ETag: W/"9-8rjb3nqDuC81Vbxmadwj3RqLz9Y"
Date: Wed, 19 Jul 2017 11:21:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{"xxx":1}
```

As you can see there is:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

present in the response even though there was no special config done in the Express app.

You can also send the `Continue` explicitly with:

```
res.writeContinue();
```

But it may be difficult to add a custom header - see this issue:

- [Feature request: passing headers to response.writeContinue() #7588 (Closed)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7588)

### Update

Here is the above example updated with a somewhat hacky but I think the only way to make it work - thanks to Robert Klep for posting it in the comments:

```
const app = require('express')();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('xxx');
  res.json({ xxx: 1 });
});
let server = app.listen(4433);    
server.on('checkContinue', (req, res) => {
  res._writeRaw('HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\nFoo: bar\r\n\r\n');
  res._sent100 = true;
  server.emit('request', req, res);
});
```

Now the response is:

```
$ echo -ne 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nExpect: 100-continue\r\n\r\n' | nc localhost 4433
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Foo: bar

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9
ETag: W/"9-8rjb3nqDuC81Vbxmadwj3RqLz9Y"
Date: Wed, 19 Jul 2017 12:17:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{"xxx":1}
```

Here's the original Gist by Robert Klep:

- https://gist.github.com/robertklep/068272f103e8cc9f09f47c3be8ca08aa

Comment: It's very hacky, but this seems to work if you want to add custom headers: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/068272f103e8cc9f09f47c3be8ca08aa

Comment: @robertklep Thanks a lot. I added it to the answer.

Comment: @rsp thx for the answer, but I had already suggested in my description that I'm aware of the _writeRaw API. And my concern still is that this seems to be private API, and it forces me to pass the full HTTP payload by myself, something I hoped I could avoid.